# Как центрировать и прижать к правому краю дивы в диве (flex)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, display

Имеется див, внутри которого несколько маленьких дивов. Нужно центрировать их по вертикали и прижать к правому краю.

Центрировать получилось с помощью `display: flex;`
Как я могу теперь пижать их к правому краю? `margin-left: auto;` делает отступ между дивами, а мне нужно прижать их к правому краю без отступов между собой.

Comment: Сделай им float:right; , но нужно будет ихнему родителю дать padding-top: calc(50% - половина высоты дива). И flex можно будет убрать.

Comment: @user190134 у родительского дива высота не фиксированная, определяется контентом, не знаю точное значение. float-right не дает эффекта, а padding-top: calc(50%) примененный к родителю - сильно растягивает его по вертикали.

Comment: Тому же блоку, которому задали `display: flex;` задайте `justify-content: flex-end;`

Comment: @stackanon Спасибо, то что нужно! Если оформите как ответ - смогу принять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блоку, которому задали `display: flex;` задайте `justify-content: flex-end;`